# Calling Class methods

Tags: python

I have 3 classes defined this way:

```
class Device:
    Some method

class SSH:
    def connect(self,type):
    # code
    def execute(self,cmd):
    # code

class Netconf:
    def connect(self,type):
    # code
    def execute(self,cmd):
    # code
```

Note SSH and Netconf classes have same method names but they do things differently.
I have an instance of class Device and would like to access methods like this-

```
d = Device()
d.connect('cli') # <-- This should call SSH method and subsequently
                 # d.execute(cmd) should call execute method from SSH class
                 # too.
d.connect('netconf') # <-- This should call Netconf method and subsequently
                     # d.execute(cmd) should call execute method from
                     # Netconf class too.
```

The question is - how do I make it happen? I want to be able to use methods of SSH/Netconf class on Device class instance 'd' based on the input.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I have edited the section to explicitly include the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by storing the type of device connected in a private `Device` attribute and then forwarding most method calls to it by adding a custom `__getattr__()` method. This is a little tricky in the `connect()` method because that's were the target device is defined (as opposed to in the `Device.__init__()` initializer).

I also changed the variable you had named `type` to `kind` to avoid colliding with the built-in module of the same name.

```
class Device(object):
    def connect(self, kind):
        if kind == 'cli':
            target = self._target = SSH()
        elif kind == 'netconf':
            target = self._target = Netconf()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unknown device {!r}'.format(kind))
        return target.connect(kind)

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self._target, name)

class SSH(object):
    def connect(self, kind):
        print('SSH.connect called with kind {!r}'.format(kind))
    def execute(self, cmd):
        print('SSH.execute called with cmd {!r}'.format(cmd))

class Netconf(object):
    def connect(self, kind):
        print('Netconf.connect called with kind {!r}'.format(kind))
    def execute(self, cmd):
        print('Netconf.execute called with cmd {!r}'.format(cmd))

d = Device()
d.connect('cli')
d.execute('cmd1')
d.connect('netconf')
d.execute('cmd2')
```

Output:

```
SSH.connect called with kind 'cli'
SSH.execute called with cmd 'cmd1'
Netconf.connect called with kind 'netconf'
Netconf.execute called with cmd 'cmd2'
```

Comment: Hi martineau, thanks for replying. This looks promising but I see a problem in the output. For netconf, it still run connect and execute methods from SSH class.

Comment: I think "if not target:" is not required.

Comment: Also, does it change things much if I add a decorator (@contextmanager) to connect method within SSH and Netconf classes?

Comment: You're right, the `if not target:` wasn't needed, nor was the `__init__()` method. In fact the code in my initial answer wasn't working properly which I have corrected. If your real `SSH` and `Netconf` `connect()` methods contain a `yield` statement, then applying the `@contextlib.contextmanager` decorator to them should work.

Comment: P.S. It might be better to apply the `@contextmanager` decorator to the `Device.connect()` method and make it `yield target.connect(kind)` instead of returning it. You can put whatever context clean-up you want following that statement.

Comment: Hi matineau, thank you for your replies, however, I think there are still fundamental problems with this solution. I see the print statements with SSH and Netconf methods show it works, but if you print self.__dict__ within these methods, you will notice that the instance definition of Device class (i.e. d) is totally lost.

Comment: It's not lost. The `self` in the `SSH` and `Netconf` methods are the instances of each of them created in the `Device.connect()` method and have nothing else intrinsically to do with that `Device` instance itself.

Comment: So if I had to access any attributes of 'self' of Device class in SSH class when connect method is called, how would I do that?

Comment: Okay, I got it. I need to pass 'self' when instantiating SSH or Netconf classes.

Comment: I suppose since the `Device` instance's `connect()` method creates the instances of the other two, it could pass the value of its `self` to them as an argument then, or soon thereafter when it explicitly calls their `connect()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the [**Strategy Pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). The `connect()` method should instantiate the appropriate class (`detach()`ing from the previous if required) and store it, and then other methods should delegate to the stored object.